# Animation always changing object position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, yaxis

I have a humanoid and I have added some animations made in **Mixamo** to it. I have made also a parent object that contains the Body with its animator attached so that I will use the relative position to its parent. However, I have some animations that occur when the humanoid is sit and also a sitting animation. I get that the humanoid instead of sitting down, it goes up and actually **sits on the air**. So **I changed the sitting animations** to modify Y on the humanoid Body so it will go down to y = -3.5f. It actually works smoothly inside the animations tab but when I run it, even though it changes its position to -3.5f after it begins to increase weirdly and in a few seconds my character is no longer sit but again in the air and to the infinite. What can I be? Here is a video that I made of my issue. https://youtu.be/tHUc7zwbI8I

[image]
[image]

Comment: lol that's magic ^^ Sorry this doesn't help but it just looks too funny. Unfortunately this looks unsolvable with the information we got here. It looks like a very complex project and you should try to removing everything else from the scene and re add it step by step in order to see what exactly is causing the issue.

Comment: Yes you are right you are not helping very much....

Comment: Can you try disabling Apply Root Motion on your Animator Component

Comment: Yes, same result. @ZohaibZaidi